# iterate though a directory of folder hierarchy %Y%m%d and perform some operation on files for each day

Tags: python, path, iteration, subdirectory, directory-structure

I have a folder which has a folder hierarchy like so %Y%m%d inside the day folder I have a folder which has multiple csv files on which I want to perform some operations. Everyday a new folder is created for the day and the files are added in it.
For example for the month of March it looks something like this.

```
└───2022
│   └───03
│       └───1
│       |    └──ATR
|       |         |-- 20220301-120000.csv
|       |         |-- 20220301-121500.csv
|       |         |-- 20220301-123000.csv
|       |         |-- 20220301-124500.csv
|       |         ...
│       └───28
│            └──ATR
|                |-- 20220328-120000.csv
|                |-- 20220328-121500.csv
|                |-- 20220328-123000.csv
|                |-- 20220328-124500.csv
```

and so on for each day.

I am really stuck here. How do I go about traversing through these directories for day and when the month is over go back a sub folder and do the same for the next month. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach to this would be to use os.walk() starting from the top-level directory then just ignore the directories you're not interested in.

A better (more efficient) approach would be to construct a directory name based on the date(s) you're interested in and go from there